# Using URL parameters in MYSQL search

Tags: php, mysql, url, search, database-design

I am trying to built a search page for products in which i have two table products and inventory, i have my product details in product and inventory details like color,size,price etc in inventory. Please suggest a solution i am really stuck and i need a better solution for a powerful design. Below are all necessary details:

**Product:**

```
product_id
product_name
product_sku
product_desc
product_category
```

**Inventory:**

```
inventory_id
product_id
inventory_color
inventory_size
```

**MY QUERY:**

```
SELECT p.product_name, p.product_sku, p.product_desc, i.inventory_color, i.inventory_color
FROM products as p
INNER JOIN  invetory as i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
```

**URL:**

```
www.abc.com/index.php?cat=shoe&color=black
```

How can i get the cat and color from URL and use them in my query? Or am i doing the right way?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: reserved words are deprecated now :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make MYSQL query from URL GET parametrs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074954/make-mysql-query-from-url-get-parametrs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are in the right path. Get the values from url using `get` or `request`

```
$category=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat']);
$color=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['color']);
```

and make your SQL as

```
SQL="SELECT p.product_name, p.product_sku, p.product_desc, i.inventory_color, i.inventory_size
FROM products as p
INNER JOIN  invetory as i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
WHERE p.product_category='".$category."' AND i.inventory_color='".$color."'";
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but another thing how can i convert my spaces(%20) to - when displaying in URL and vice verse when fetching data from database

Comment: i just noticed one thing :) My parameters are different from my db fields, e.g. for above particular scenario it will work, what if user only clicks cat how would i handle that in product category, i am trying to use the facet search, which has many parameters coming.

Comment: Can you tell me what all parameters you want to search ?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch values from an url.
    you can use " $_GET['parameter'] "

```
$color = $_GET['color'];
$category = $_GET['cat'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with $_GET like:

```
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

using PDO, something like -

```
$dbh = new PDO(...)
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT p.product_name, p.product_sku, p.product_desc, i.inventory_color
                      FROM products as p
                      INNER JOIN  invetory as i ON p.product_id = i.product_id 
                      WHERE p.cat = ? AND i.inventory_color = ?');
$sth->execute(array($_GET['cat'], $_GET['color']));
$results = $sth->fetchAll();
```

from example at  http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php