# Create MySQL query from URL GET parameters

Tags: php, sql, search

hey i am a beginner in PHP and MYSQL, i am stuck with a basic problem. How can i make my query  from URL parameters

**MY URL EXAMPLES:**

```
www.abs.com/index.php?cat=shoes

www.abs.com/index.php?cat=shoes&subcat=sports

www.abs.com/index.php?cat=shoes&subcat=sports&color=blue
```

How can i handle this kind of URL's in my query, that is just my example query, i have a large set of fields for both of my tables. I need help with the WHERE part of query, main problem is i am passing (cat) in my URL where it is (b.category) in my database.

**MY QUERY:**

```
select a.p_id, a.p_name, a.p_prize, b.p_id b.color, b.category, b.subcategory
FROM products a INNER JOIN details b ON a.p_id=b.p_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to process the URL using PHP by assigning the URL parameters to PHP variables:

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
$subcat = $_GET['subcat'];
$color= $_GET['color'];
```

Then you can use these variables to create a MySQL query string:

```
$queryString = "SELECT a.p_id, a.p_name, a.p_prize, b.p_id b.color, b.category, b.subcategory
FROM products a INNER JOIN details b ON a.p_id=b.p_id WHERE b.category = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $cat ) . "' AND b.subcategory = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $subcat ) . "' AND b.color = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $color ) . "' ";
```

You can then use this query sting to query the database.

Comment: Don't put unsanitised user input directly into the database.

Comment: I would agree in the case of inserting in to a database, though the query string above simple selects from a database and as such should be safe. Though best practice would be to use _mysql_real_escape_string_. Answer edited to show best practice.

Comment: Go for mysqli or pdo :-)

Comment: @egd if you believe that you need to read up more on [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759603/mysql-injection-use-select-query-to-update-delete). Especially as people are moving over to MySQLi which supports multiple queries.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy enough:

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
$query = "SELECT a.p_id, a.p_name, a.p_prize, b.p_id b.color, b.category, b.subcategory
    FROM products a 
    INNER JOIN details b ON a.p_id=b.p_id
    WHERE b.category = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($cat)) . "'";
```

Please note a couple of things, firstly the use of mysql_real_escape_string to help protect your database. It helps protect against SQL injections, although isn't entirely foolproof.

Also note that **MySQL_*** is depreciated. You shouldn't be writing queries in it any more. You should look into [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

Comment: :) how can i handle when user selects color, category or brand at the same time, real question was my names are not the same as of my db fields

Comment: That would depend on where colour, category and brand are in your database. If they are in details then just add more clauses onto the end of the query using `AND`.

Comment: my database fields in query are i.inventory_color, p.product_category where values in my URL are cat and color

Comment: Can you update your original question? You need to include more detail so add your full table structure.

Comment: [detailed Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049860/using-url-parameters-in-mysql-search?noredirect=1#comment33476843_22049860)

Comment: @JunaidRehman Generally, it is better to update an existing question when adding more detail instead of creating a new question, as valid and useful answers are already posted and we don't want to lose them. Failing that, you'd want to link to your new question in a comment on your post, not on an answer; that way everybody can easily see it. As it stands, since you've already done it, I've marked this question as a duplicate of your new one.

Comment: i am new to stack over flow, instead of showing me the right way its not good you give me negative points